# Elements of the coset $G/H$, where $G=\text{GL}^+(2)$ and $H=\text{SO}(2)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.5848.pdf), in section $2$, a method to write the elements of the coset of $G/H$ is provided for $\text{GL}(4)$, but I am interested in $\text{GL}^+(2)$.

My matrix representation of $\mathfrak{gl}(2)$ is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a+x& -b+y\\
b+y & a-x
\end{bmatrix}
$$

My matrix representation of $\mathfrak{so}(2)$ is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0& -b\\
b & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

---

Reading the paper, it states that the element $g$ of $G$ can be decomposed as $g=\gamma h$, where

$$
\gamma = \exp \left( \begin{bmatrix}
a+x& +y\\
y & a-x
\end{bmatrix} \right) \in G/H
$$

and where

$$
h = \exp \left( \begin{bmatrix}
0& -b\\
b & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right) \in H
$$

Is this correct, or no?

I am suspicious of the argument, because to me

$$
\exp \left( \begin{bmatrix}
a+x& y\\
y & a-x
\end{bmatrix} \right)\exp \left( \begin{bmatrix}
0& -b\\
b & 0
\end{bmatrix} \right) \neq \exp \left( \begin{bmatrix}
a+x& -b+y\\
b+y & a-x
\end{bmatrix} \right)
$$

Thus, $\gamma h$ does not appear to realize all elements of $G$. Or do we not care about some missing elements for cosets?

Comment: $GL_2\Bbb R$ is not connected. Its elements with negative determinant are not expressible as products of exponentials. Physics literature is notorious (in my mind anway) for ignoring things like $\pi_0$ or $\pi_1$.

Comment: @runway44 I am almost certain the author meant to use $GL_4^+(R)$. Can we consider the case for $GL_2^+(R)$?

Comment: You may be interested in "knit products"; sometimes we have $G=HK$ and $H\cap K$ is trivial, but $H,K$ do not commute and $G$ is not a direct product of them. This means  your intuition is not so helpful. That said, I suspect it is still false; consider $[\begin{smallmatrix}-1&1\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}]$. (BTW, I think your product of exponentials is equal to ${\rm GL}^+_1(\Bbb R){\rm SO}_0(1,1){\rm SO}(2)$.) Dunno offhand if this generalizes to ${\rm GL}_4^+\Bbb R$.

Comment: @runway44 In equation 2.7, the author seems to suggest that one can represent the elements of GL(4) using the multiplication of two exponentials:  1) the generators of shears and dilations, and 2) the generators of the Lorentz transformation. He is wrong, right? That because the generators do not commute?

Comment: @runway44 In Equation 2.6 he states "Group elements g ∈ G are uniquely decomposed as g = γh where h ∈ H and $\gamma(ξ) = exp[ \frac{i}{2}ξ · T] ∈ G/H$". But this is also false because $G = \exp[ \frac{i}{2}ξ · T + \frac{i}2 u ·  J] \neq \exp[ \frac{i}{2}ξ · T ]  \exp[  \frac{i}2 u ·  J ]$  because T and J do not commute?

Comment: Reread the first sentence of my second comment; I point out exactly why commutativity is irrelevant. I elaborated in my answer. Also: my comment about $[{-1~~~1\atop~~0~-1}]=\exp(\pi[{0~-1\atop1~~~0}])\exp([{0~1\atop0~0}])$ is not relevant either. I was mixing it up with a related fact: this matrix is a product of exponentials, but not *itself* an exponential.

Answer (score 1):

In the $GL_2(\mathbb R)$ case, the author's conclusion is correct, but it doesn't really come from Lie algebra manipulations. For $GL_n(\mathbb R)$, and for other reductive groups, there is the Cartan decomposition $G=\mathrm{exp}(\mathfrak s)\cdot K$, where $K$ is the maximal compact obtained as exponentiating the $+1$ eigenspace for a chosen Cartan involution (e.g., the standard $\gamma\to -\gamma^\top$), and $\mathfrak s$ is the $-1$ eigenspace. The latter is *not* a Lie subalgebra. In the standard case, it is symmetric matrices, while the Lie algebra $\mathfrak k$ of $K$ is *skew*-symmetric matrices.

For $GL_n(\mathbb R)$, the proof of this decomposition is just about the spectral theorem for self-adjoint operators on $\mathbb R^n$...

Comment: Can $\exp s$ be the SO group here?

Comment: The Lie algebra $\mathfrak k$ exponentiates to $K=SO(2)$.

Comment: For your first sentence, I would clarify you're saying author's conclusion is correct, not the OP's from the comments.

Comment: @runway44, good idea. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if $\exp(X+Y)\ne\exp(X)\exp(Y)$ in general, that doesn't stop elements of the form $\exp(X_1+Y_1)$ from being expressible as $\exp(X_2)\exp(Y_2)$ for a pair $X_2,Y_2$ which is *different* from $X_1,Y_1$. So your observation about lie algebra elements not commuting, and therefore $\exp$ not being a homomorphism, is not at all helpful for your conclusion about the author being wrong.

The situation we have here is a Lie group $G$ and subgroup $K$, with lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{k}$, with a complementary vector subspace $\mathfrak{p}$ to $\mathfrak{k}$ within $\mathfrak{g}$ (i.e. $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}\oplus\mathfrak{p}$ as vector spaces) which is not necessarily itself a lie subalgebra, and the question is if $\exp(\mathfrak{g})=\exp(\mathfrak{k})\exp(\mathfrak{p})$, despite the fact that $\exp(X+Y)\ne\exp(X)\exp(Y)$.

In particular, this situation has $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}\oplus\mathfrak{p}$ as part of the Cartan decomposition, as Garrett points out. For illustration, let's look at a different situation: knit products, where the complementary vector subspace is in fact a lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$ just like $\mathfrak{k}$. Let me change letters to be more consistent with the literature. We have subgroups $H,K\le G$ for which $G=HK$ (i.e. all $g\in G$ are expressible as $g=hk$ with $h\in H,k\in K$) and $H\cap K$ is trivial (i.e. if $g=hk$ then $h\in H,k\in K$ are unique). If we added the condition that elements of $H$ and $K$ commute with each other, then we could say $G=H\times K$ is an internal direct product, but a knit product has no such condition. In other words, the multiplication map $H\times K\to G$ given by $(h,k)\mapsto hk$ is a diffeomorphism but not necessarily a homomorphism, if $G$ is a knit product of $H$ and $K$.

Here is perhaps the simplest example: the (orientation-preserving component of the) affine group $\mathrm{Aff}_0(1,\mathbb{R})$, consisting of maps $x\mapsto ax+b$ ($a>0$). We can model such maps as matrices $[\begin{smallmatrix} a&b\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}]$ acting on vectors $[\begin{smallmatrix} x\\1 \end{smallmatrix}]$. This group is a knit product of subgroups $K=\{[\begin{smallmatrix} a&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}]\}\cong\mathbb{R}^\times$ and $H=\{[\begin{smallmatrix}1&h\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}]\}\cong\mathbb{R}$. Indeed, a little bit of work shows:

$$ \exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)=
\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}x&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right)
\exp\left(\begin{bmatrix}0&\frac{1}{x}(1-e^{-x})y\\0&0\end{bmatrix}\right). $$

For $\mathrm{GL}_2\mathbb{R}$ in particular, it is a good exercise to verify (a) any rotation matrix is an exponential of an antisymmetric matrix, (b) any symmetric matrix is an exponential of a symmetric matrix, and (c) every invertible matrix is a symmetric matrix times a rotation matrix.